# What's the best practice for persist session between Activities in Android?

Tags: android, httpclient

I have a HttpClient to communicate with my server, and I want to persist my session to keep user logged between Activities.

Up till now, I have used a Service to back up my HttpClient, including a background thread to do the heavy work.

Another way to do this I know through my googling is that save the Cookie in a local file/xml/database, and check if it exists, if it exists, then use it in the new HttpClient I created each Activity.

Which way is better or are there even better ways to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally would go with the cookie. Cookies are commonly used to do just this. HttpClient accepts a CookieStore that you can have backed by a file. When the cookie is updated, just update the file and when it has to be retrieved either use an in memory copy or read the file. I don't know how your would back up your session with just a service. The Service would have to save some state somewhere. Serializing an HttpClient does not seem to be possible. So I would just implement a CookieStore.

[CookieStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/CookieStore.html)

Comment: I can use a service to persist the HttpClient instance in one session, that's enough for applications that requires login everytime.

Comment: I guess I am confused, what is the service persisting? You can't write the HttpClient to disk. Or are you saying the service just acts as a singleton that holds the client? If so I think passing data back in forth will be come more troublesome then just using a HttpClient with a cookie store and a shared place in memory to have your activities pull it from (maybe in an Application object if you went that route).

Comment: The service is not closed during one session of the application(even in different activities). So the HttpClient is never collected because the service object is still holding its reference. When I want to use it I just call the IBinder to get the instance of th Service object and get HttpClient from there